# Units of drawEllipse

Tags: c#, draw, ellipse, units-of-measurement

I was looking on the internet but I didn't find an answer. I need to know in what kind of units drawEllipse works: pixels, centimetres...

I also need to know if there is a easy way to change that units (I need it on centimetres).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let's say we have Winforms here. Then lets look what documentation states about [Form.Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is measured in Pixel. You can check it by printing this information onto your `Form` using the [PageUnit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Graphics.PageUnit.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 14), Brushes.Black, 50, 50);
}
```

This property can also be used to set the desired unit of measurement like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), 100, 100, 25, 30);
}
```

Now you should have a black ellipse with a width of 2.5 cm and a height of 3.0 cm at the coordinates of 10 cm in X and 10 cm in Y dimension

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't look too carefully.

`DrawEllipse` is a method of the [`System.Drawing.Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) class. `Graphics` implements the [`PageUnit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit(v=vs.110).aspx) property which:

> Gets or sets the unit of measure used for page coordinates in this Graphics.

The possible values are given by the [`GraphicsUnit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration.